# Unable to reinstall Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, system-installation, 18.04, acpi

I am unable to reinstall Ubuntu Server 18.04. The hardware is an Intel i3 8100 processor and a b360 motherboard.

I had Ubuntu Server running until I changed the `fstab` file, that’s when I started getting errors. I formatted the disk and tried to reinstall it and that is where I am stuck at.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76901/discussion-on-question-by-stijn-unable-to-reinstall-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your computer is too new for the built-in graphics drivers to work.

Maybe you can find Intel microcode that works via the following link, or some other link when searching for 'Intel i3 8100 processor linux' (without quotes).

[Downloads for Intel® Core™ i3-8100 Processor (6M Cache, 3.60 GHz)](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/126688/Intel-Core-i3-8100-Processor-6M-Cache-3-60-GHz-)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not sure if I am able to install it since i can't boot into Linux. I'm starting to think that it might be a problem with my motherboard

Comment: @Stijn, You may be right about that. But I suggest that you browse the internet according to my tip in the answer and read the relevant links about 'Intel i3 8100 processor linux' (without quotes). You may find something that works.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the motherboard resolved the issue, I want to thank everybody for their help!